# Simple thread program doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi, I'm a novice java programmer towards thread. And I'm stuck on this simple Java program

```
public class Multi extends Thread{  
    public void run() { 
        try{ 
            System.out.println("running...");
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.print(e);   
        }
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        Multi t1=new Multi();  
        t1.run();//fine, but does not start a separate call stack  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Answers already made, buy I must admit having some fun about so much messed up in so short code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are started using the start method. Calling `t1.run()` method just synchronously executes the `run` method within the same Thread.

```
t1.start();
```

Read: [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Still it shows me this kind of error "Could not find the main class: Multi."

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: Need more info here. Is the class in a package? What is the run command?

Comment: There's no such thing. I just picked up the program from a website, here     http://www.javatpoint.com/what-if-we-call-run()-method-directly

Comment: Did you _compile_ the class before running it?

Comment: Allright...everything here is fair and good...I don't know why it didn't run earlier, but now when i tried running it on a different pc i worked out perfectly well. Strange!!!

Comment: you're welcome - on a related note, do read [`implements Runnable vs. extends Thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Answer (score 1):

**Java** threads are triggered by the following method:

```
t1.start() // This starts a new thread
```

While the following:

```
t1.run();// This calls the run method in the same thread
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads Are Started With [`Thread.Start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

And Look on Thread Life Cycle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
t1.run();// just calls the run method (like any other method) in the same thread.

use t1.start() // starts a new thread.
```